# Ruby module inclusions and class variables

Tags: ruby, module, mixins, class-variables, inclusion

I am trying to understand module inclusions with class variables. I thought that including a module with class variables would also include the class variables into the class definition.

**This works as intended:**

```
module A 
  @@my_name = "rick"
  def print_name
    puts @@my_name
  end
end

class Y 
  include A
  extend A
end

Y.print_name
```

**But this does not:**

```
module A

  def self.included(klass)
    klass.include B
    klass.extend C
  end

  module B
    @@my_name = "bob"
  end

  module C 
    def print_name
      puts @@my_name
    end
  end

end

class Y
  include A
end

Y.print_name
```

I was expecting "**bob**" but instead i got:

> uninitialized class variable @@my_name in A::C

Answer (score 1):

It would work if you use [Module#`class_variable_get`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.3/Module.html#method-i-class_variable_get):

```
module C
  def print_name
    class_variable_get(:@@my_name)
  end
end
Y.print_name
#=> "bob"
```

I think the problem was that when in `module C` you say `puts @@my_name` it does not yet know about the `@@my_name`, because in `module C` you have never set it (it is set in `module B` and `C` does not know about `B`).

Answer (score -1):

What if you try to prepend the module? That adds a module to a class, but inserts them BEFORE the class's methods. This is a way to ensure that if there is a variable naming conflict, the module will win-out.

And I mean this more as a comment, but my user rating isn't high enough yet for comments, so I apologize if this is off the mark.